# How do I write a LINQ Expression Tree that filters on a method of a property?

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a collection of objects with properties on it:

```
ParentObject parentObj
{
    string SomeProperty1
    string SomeProperty2
}
```

Before querying on these properties, they need to be made ToLower() and Trim(). I understand that I can do:

```
Expression.Call(pe, typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", Type.EmptyTypes)); // Or ToLower
```

And

```
Expression.Property(pe, typeof(string).GetProperty("SomeProperty1"));
```

But how do I combine them?

I need something to the equivalent of

```
from query in parentObjCollection
where query.SomeProperty1.Trim() == "asdf"
select query
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need an expression?  What's wrong with where query.SomeProperty1.Trim() == "asdf"

Comment: I need to build these expressions dynamically based on XML input that may or may not be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expression.Property` returns an expression itself, you can use that as the first parameter of the call (full example):

```
var parent = new ParentObject{ SomeProperty1 = "    test" };
var pe = Expression.Constant(parent);
var property = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(ParentObject).GetProperty("SomeProperty1"));
var call = Expression.Call(property, typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", Type.EmptyTypes));

var result = Expression.Lambda(call).Compile().DynamicInvoke();

Console.WriteLine(result); // -> "test"
```

Note that I had to modify your `Expression.Property` call.